# value || is not a member of String - scala

Tags: scala

I am using string filter function like:

```
val strings = List("hi","I","am","here") //this list is a stream of words from Twitter
val mystrings = strings.filter(word => !word.contains("I" || "sam") // I need filter out certain stop words
```

to filter certain words. But I am getting compilation error saying that - value `||` is not a member of `String`. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `contains` on `String` takes a `String` as an argument:

```
"foo".contains("foo") //True
```

So, the compiler is trying to interpret `"I" || "sam"` as a `String`, since that is the argument to `contains`.  In Scala, this statement would be equivalent to `"I".||("sam")` (calling the `||` method on `"I"`).  Since there is no method `||` on `String`, this fails to compile.

What you probably meant is `!(word.contains("I") || word.contains("sam"))`.  This makes sense, since we are now calling `||` on the `Boolean` that is returned by `word.contains("I")`, and `||` is a method on `Boolean` (as documented [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Boolean@%7C%7C%28x:Boolean%29:Boolean)).  So your whole statement might be:

```
strings.filter(word => !(word.contains("I") || word.contains("sam"))
```

Which is also equivalent to:

```
strings.filter(word => !word.contains("I") && !word.contains("sam"))
```

If you end up with a lot of phrases to filter, you could also flip it around:

```
val segments = Set("I", "sam")
strings.filter(word => segments.forall(segment => !word.contains(segment)))
//Equivalent
strings.filter(word => !segments.exists(word.contains))
```

Comment: If you use a set for strings you can also use & to produce the intersection: Set("I", "sam") & Set("clam", "ham", "sam") gives you Set("sam")